# default / custom values for variables in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

i have a situation in C++ where i need to:

1) define a "default" value for static const variables in a namespace declared/defined in an object module

2) allow several "main" programs to "overwrite" these values using "custom" values

each "main" program has its own build folder and its own copy of the object module, so "main" programs are completely independent of each other:

e.g.

```
/mainProgramA/build/mainProgramA.o
/mainProgramA/build/Module.o
/mainProgramB/build/mainProgramB.o
/mainProgramB/build/Module.o
```

also, at any one time, either the default values or custom values will be defined/declared, but not both.  if the compiler "finds" the custom values, they will be used, if not, the defaults will be used.

i can't use weak symbols without namespaces because i need the namespaces to avoid naming clashes. i can't use weak symbols with namespaces because i get "error: weak declaration of ... must be public".  i could use a class perhaps, but all the values are known at compile time and not variable.  What is the simplest and most elegant way to do this?

to clarify, i'm trying to do something like this:

DefaultValues.h:

```
namespace ConfigParams {
    static const int param1 = 1;
    static const int param2 = 2;
}
```

CustomValues.h:

```
namespace ConfigParams {
    static const int param1 = 100;
    static const int param2 = 200;
}
```

Module.h:

```
#include "DefaultValues.h"
class Module {
public:
    static void printParam1();
}
```

Module.cpp:

```
#include "Module.h"

void Module::printParam1() 
{
    printf("%d\n", param1);
}
```

mainUsingDefaultValues.cpp (which will link in a copy of module.o where param1 == 1):

```
#include "Module.h"

...
Module::printParam1(); // Should print "1"
```

mainUsingCustomValues.cpp (which will link in a copy of module.o where param1 == 100):

```
#include "CustomValues.h"
#include "Module.h"

...
Module::printParam1(); // Should print "100"
```

Comment: Include either `DefaultValues.h` or `CustomValues.h`, but not both. You can do it differently, but I'd say use `#define` in `CustomValues.h` and then check if it's defined in `Module.h` and include `DefaultValues.h` based on that.

Comment: @AzzA I guess that's no way of doing that. Constants should be compiled and linked with absolute address therefor when you define class two times with different constants it should result in one in real application.

Comment: @Vyktor I think the question was how to exclude default values when custom values are specified. You can do it with preprocessor... Or maybe I misunderstood. I understand it as you either select one or another and OP author needs way to select it. You cannot use both, of course, you can include one or another.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ConfigParams::param1` (or `using namespace ConfigParams;`). Now to answer your question, If you keep different `param1` in different `namespace` and then leverage `using namespace ...;` accordingly, it would elegantly solve your problem. Presently feeling lazy to transform this comment into an answer.

Comment: What about code in other TUs? If there's "somelibrary.cpp" that also uses `ConfigParams::param1`, then "allow the main program to overwrite these values" contradicts "the values are known at compile time", because although they're known at the compile time of mainUsingCustomValues.cpp, they're not known at the compile time of somelibrary.cpp.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think, OP author meant that he compiles his `Module.cpp` together with his `main.cpp`, and just needs to make several pre-defined constant selections based on what he needs for different `main.cpp`'s. It's not really a separate `.lib` file he just tries to link... I hope.

Comment: @AzzA: still, if Module.cpp contains a definition of `param1` with a different value from the value in main.cpp, then the function in `Module` will print the value that was defined for Module.cpp, not the value that was defined for main.cpp. Doesn't matter whether Module.cpp is in a separate .lib or not, if you want a "compile-time constant" then you need to define it with the same value in every TU.

Comment: thanks guys, AzzA is right, the question is how to exclude default values when custom values are specified.

Comment: @SteveJessop mainUsingCustomValues.cpp and somelibrary.cpp will have completely independent build output directories and so they will have different copies of module.o.  the 2 different copies can have different values of param1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// File: CustomValues.h
#define MY_CUSTOM_VALUES
namespace ConfigParams 
{
 static const int param1 = 100;
 static const int param2 = 200;
}


// File: DefaultValues.h
#ifndef MY_CUSTOM_VALUES
namespace ConfigParams 
{
 static const int param1 = 1;
 static const int param2 = 2;
}
#endif
```

You can make it more flexible if you need it.

EDIT: Just in case I misunderstood the question. This way user of your library will be defaulted to `DefaultValues.h`, unless they include `CustomValues.h` before `Module.h`. You can have either one or another, but not both.

```
#include "Module.h"
#include "CustomValues.h"
```

will not compile, since you'll be redefining your constants.

And just to make sure, you'll need to include `CustomValues.h` in `Module.cpp` as well. So, probably, it's better to make a `#ifdef` switch inside `Module.h` and make user  `#define MY_CUSTOM_VALUES` somewhere before any `Module.h` includes:

```
// File: Module.h
#include "My_Constants.h" // #define MY_CUSTOM_VALUES can go here
#ifdef MY_CUSTOM_VALUES
#include "CustomValues.h"
#elif
#include "DefaultValues.h"
#endif

class Module
{
 public:
  static void printParam1();
}   
// End of Module.h

// File: Module.cpp
#include "Module.h"

void Module::printParam1() 
{
 printf("%d\n", ConfigParams::param1);
}
// End of Module.cpp
```

Comment: I wander... Static tells compiler&linker that this variable should be initialized in the beginning of program and should be there whole time. Doesn't it? And when linker sees two variables with the same name, both static... Doesn't it (shouldn't it?) use the same "absolute address in memory"?

Comment: @Vyktor Once again, `#define` is for preprocessor to bypass default definition, if custom is supplied. The default ones will be eliminated by preprocessor and won't make it to compilation.

Comment: I understand that, but I though that `static const` has global scope (after linking) and therefore linker tries to put them all into the same "memory spot". Or are they all in local scope unless `extern` is used?

Comment: @Vyktor `static`, `const` and `static const` have internal linkage.

Comment: @user1151522 Glad I could help. If you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to accept it ;).

Comment: Just a small mod.  In this case, the user has to create the file "My_Constants.h", so I'm thinking, instead of `#include "My_Constants.h"`, I will just `#include "CustomValues.h"` and do `#ifndef MY_CUSTOM_VALUES` then `#include "DefaultVAlues.h"`.  Meaning, if the user wants custom values, the user will have to create "CustomValues.h", insert #define MY_CUSTOM_VALUES and define/declare the custom values.  If they want default values, they will create an empty "CustomValues.h".  I will try this out and see if it works!

Comment: @user1151522 File `My_Constants.h` can have some more meaningful name and you can put there ALL of your preprocessor constants for different scenarios etc. Sort of, one place where you should edit/look if you want to change/check these sort of things.

Comment: @user1151522 Also, on a side note, you should think of using header guards (or `#pragma once`).